# How come Kalkeya Chief knew about what Bijjaladeva said a day before war

Tags: plot-explanation, baahubali-the-beginning

In *Baahubali:The Beginning*, During war, Kalakeya chief asks Sivagami, "You will declare King whoever kills me among both princes". This quote was said by Bijjaladeva a day before the war. My question is, how Kalakeya Chief knew about this? His spy Saket was arrested already.

Comment: word travels fast when the news is that big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was never elaborated in the film but there can be two possibilities for it:

1. As mentioned by Tejashwini's comment, word travels fast when the news is that big. As it was a big deal for the kingdom and most probably words got around and reached to Kalakeya.
2. Kalakeya has another spy which was never revealed.